# Android-simple-facebook lib, get user birthday date

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-simple-facebook

[The question in github](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook/issues/165)

I'm using android-simple-facebook lib to make login in facebook and get some user data.

In this case the problem that I'm facing is that I can't get the user's birthdate data.

I've set the permissions to the `SimpleFacebookConfiguration` object

```
private Permission[] permissions = new Permission[]{
Permission.EMAIL,
Permission.USER_BIRTHDAY,
Permission.PUBLIC_PROFILE,
Permission.PUBLISH_ACTION
};
```

and this profile's permissions to get the data

```
Profile.Properties properties = new Profile.Properties.Builder()
.add(Profile.Properties.ID)
.add(Profile.Properties.FIRST_NAME)
.add(Profile.Properties.LAST_NAME)
.add(Profile.Properties.BIRTHDAY)
.add(Profile.Properties.AGE_RANGE)
.add(Profile.Properties.EMAIL)
.add(Profile.Properties.GENDER)
.build();
```

But I can't get the data from any of them. Any idea?

Comment: Why not user this example ? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/
It allows to you to get user data.

Comment: I'm using android-simple-facebook...not only the sdk

Comment: Are you asking a user that have a role on the app or a user that doesn't have a role on the app? If you asking a user that doesn't have a role on the app you need to get that permission approved by Facebook first

Answer (score 0):

To request for new permission

```
 private Permission[] permissions = new Permission[]{
    Permission.EMAIL,
    Permission.USER_BIRTHDAY,

    };

     SimpleFacebook.getInstance().requestNewPermissions(permissions, new OnNewPermissionsListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFail(String reason) {
                    //mResult.setText(reason);
                    System.out.println(""+reason);
                }

                @Override
                public void onException(Throwable throwable) {
                   // mResult.setText(throwable.getMessage());
                    System.out.println(""+throwable.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String accessToken, List<Permission> acceptedPermissions, List<Permission> declinedPermissions) {
                    //   showGrantedPermissions();
                    mSimpleFacebook.getProfile(properties, onProfileListener);
                    if (declinedPermissions != null && declinedPermissions.size() > 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User declined few permissions: " + declinedPermissions.toString(),      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                }

            });

Profile.Properties properties = new Profile.Properties.Builder()
.add(Profile.Properties.ID)
.add(Profile.Properties.FIRST_NAME)
.add(Profile.Properties.LAST_NAME)
.add(Profile.Properties.BIRTHDAY)
.add(Profile.Properties.AGE_RANGE)
.add(Profile.Properties.EMAIL)
.add(Profile.Properties.GENDER)
.build();
```